# How to propagate row count value from toracleRow component to tJava component in Talend?

Tags: sql-server, talend

I'm trying to fetch the row count value of a particular merge statement which has been present in tOracleRowcomponent. But while propagating this count value to tJava Component, it is fetching the value as null for MS SQL server.

How can I propagate the count value from one component to other in case of MSSql server ?

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT`..?

Comment: Do I need to use separate component for @@ROWCOUNT ? I've tried using both merge query and SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as COUNT;  in same component and added count column in the schema and tried to propogate the count value. But it is coming as null

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking the components with **main**  change it to **OnComponentOK** .
If it is not working please post your job design this will help .